# Call to undefined function wordpress listing_categories

Tags: errors

What is wrong with this 2 lines? im getting Call to undefined function fw_ext_extension_get_listing_categories()

```
    $categories = fw_ext_extension_get_listing_categories ( $atts['cat'], 'models' );
$sort_classes = fw_ext_extension_get_sort_classes ( $posts->posts, $categories, '', 'models' );
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the function

```
/**
 * @param int|array $term_ids
 *
 * @return array|WP_Error
 */
function fw_ext_extension_get_listing_categories( $term_ids, $extension_name ) {

    $args = array(
        'hide_empty'    => true
    );

    if ( ! empty( $term_ids ) ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $term_ids ) ) {
            $args['parent'] = $term_ids;
        } elseif ( is_array( $term_ids ) ) {
            $args['include'] = $term_ids;
        }
    }

    $ext_extension_settings = fw()->extensions->get( $extension_name )->get_settings();
    $taxonomy               = $ext_extension_settings['taxonomy_name'];

    $categories = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $categories ) && ! empty( $categories ) ) {

        foreach ( $categories as $key => $category ) {
            $children                     = get_term_children( $category->term_id, $taxonomy );
            $categories[ $key ]->children = $children;

            //remove empty categories
            if ( ( $category->count == 0 ) && ( is_wp_error( $children ) || empty( $children ) ) ) {
                unset( $categories[ $key ] );
            }
        }

        return $categories;
    }

    return array();
}

/**
 * @param WP_Post[] $items
 * @param array $categories
 * @param string $prefix
 *
 * @return array
 */
function fw_ext_extension_get_sort_classes( array $items, array $categories, $prefix = '', $extension_name ) {

    $ext_extension_settings = fw()->extensions->get( $extension_name )->get_settings();
    $taxonomy = $ext_extension_settings['taxonomy_name'];
    $classes            = array();
    $categories_classes = array();
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        $class_name = '';
        $terms      = wp_get_post_terms( $item->ID, $taxonomy );

        if ( ( ! empty( $terms ) ) && ! empty ( $categories ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                    if ( $term->term_id == $category->term_id ) {
                        $class_name .= $prefix . $category->slug . ' ';
                        $categories_classes[ $term->term_id ] = true;
                    } else {
                        if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category->children, true ) ) {
                            $class_name .= $prefix . $category->slug . ' ';
                            $categories_classes[ $term->term_id ] = true;
                        }
                    }
                    $classes[ $item->ID ] = $class_name;
                }
            }
        //if no terms
        } else {
            $classes[ $item->ID ] = '';
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this might be a custom function in your code that is no longer defined. I can't find that function on Google, leading me to believe it is proprietary. You could search your codebase with something like `grep -rn 'function fw_ext_extension_get_listing_categories'`.

Comment: @phatskat i edit the post with the function.

Comment: the next question would be: "Where are these functions defined?" It seems that your functions are defined in a place that is inaccessible to wherever you are calling them. For example, if you're editing `/single.php`, and your functions exist in `myfunctions.php`, you need to include that file. More detail would help us figure this out.

Comment: The functions are defined in a plugin `mwt-unyson-extensions.php` and im using in another plugin named `Ajax Load More`

Comment: @phatskat `wp-content/plugins/mwt-unyson-extensions/mwt-unyson-extensions.php` and `wp-content/plugins/ajax-load-more`

Comment: Are both of those plugins enabled if you go to `/wp-admin/plugins.php` ?